# Error in json date conversion

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In my Web application(ASP NET MVC) am returing an json object(return json(object)) from controller to js via ajax. Am getting the date property in the format /Date(1433442540000)/. When am converting this date to original date format which i expect was not getting properly. I just use the below code

new Date(parseInt(date.match(/\d+/).toString()))

am getting wrong date . Could anyone just how json converting date whether it will convert the date based on time zone or any other ?

Comment: What do you mean _"getting wrong date"_? What are you getting and what are your expecting?

Comment: I meant that date am saving in database comes exactly the same before converting to json in controller side. After conversion it becomes as /Date(1433442540000)/ and then in javascript side when am converting it gives a different date format.

I Couldnt find where i was wrong.

Comment: Again - What are you getting and what are your expecting?

Comment: Please find the details mentioned below:
6/12/2015 12:00:00 AM - date which i expect in client side
/Date(1434081600000)/ - date formatted after json conversion
Fri Jun 12 2015 04:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - date i got in client.

Comment: Then either just return a formatted date string from the server (rather than `DateTime`), or you will need javascript to build your own string representation in the client (a c# `DateTIme` is not the same as a javascript `Date` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can pass the date value in string format instead of passing DateTime format from server (C# code) side or you can use [Globalize.js](http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/05/globalizejs-number-and-date.html) to format a date value in client (Javascript) side.